# How can I plot this data?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot this data:

```
h = 1
m = 1

E1 = (((h**2)/(2*m)) * ((((1*np.pi)/2)+((1*np.pi)/2))**2))
E2 = (((h**2)/(2*m)) * ((((2*np.pi)/2)+((2*np.pi)/2))**2))
E3 = (((h**2)/(2*m)) * ((((3*np.pi)/2)+((3*np.pi)/2))**2))
E4 = (((h**2)/(2*m)) * ((((4*np.pi)/2)+((4*np.pi)/2))**2))

k1 = ((((1*np.pi)/2)+((1*np.pi)/2))**2)
k2 = ((((2*np.pi)/2)+((2*np.pi)/2))**2)
k3 = ((((3*np.pi)/2)+((3*np.pi)/2))**2)
k4 = ((((4*np.pi)/2)+((4*np.pi)/2))**2)


E = list[E1, E2, E3, E4]
k = list[k1, k2, k3, k4]

plt.scatter(k,E)
plt.show()
```

The `list` function doesn't seem to work for this. I don't think it can get the pre-defined values. Using `np.array` also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think maybe you have a parentheses typo in your code, because you have `n*np.pi/2 + n*np.pi/2` which is equivalent to `n*np.pi`.  Did you want `n*np.pi/2 + (n*np.pi/2)**2`?

Comment: I realised I made a mistake with my parentheses, but that's not what I wanted. It's all fixed now and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you define your lists is the issue.

Try:

```
E = [E1, E2, E3, E4]
k = [k1, k2, k3, k4]
```

Or if you want to use numpy:

```
E = np.array([E1, E2, E3, E4])
k = np.array([k1, k2, k3, k4])
```

Comment: Oh yes, silly me. Okay, that works. Any idea why all my E values output 0?

Comment: yes, ((h**2)/(2*m)) is 0 because it is integer manipulation. Try with h = 1.0 and m = 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a suggestion but I wanted to write out enough code that wouldn't fit in a comment.

Instead of writing out four nearly identical lines, you can define a function:

```
def E(n, h=1.0, m=1.0):
    return (((h**2)/(2*m)) * ((((n*np.pi)/2)+((n*np.pi)/2))**2))
```

Note that it accepts values for `h` and `m` as arguments, but if none are provided, it will use `1.0` as default for both.  This can even be simplified further, just by cleaning up the notation a bit (e.g., you have `something/2 + something/2`, which is equivalent to `something`, see my comment on your question)

```
def E(n, h=1.0, m=1.0):
    return (.5*h**2/m) * (n*np.pi)**2
```

And similarly for `k`:

```
def k(n):
    return (n*np.pi)**2
```

The best thing about this, is that you can now do this all at once without manually building that list:

```
>>> ns = np.arange(1,5)  # this is np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> E(ns)
array([  4.9348022 ,  19.7392088 ,  44.4132198 ,  78.95683521])
>>> k(ns)
array([   9.8696044 ,   39.4784176 ,   88.82643961,  157.91367042])
```

Obviously this precise code won't work for you given the parenthesis typo, but I hope it helps with using numpy!  This is the entire code at once:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def E(n, h=1.0, m=1.0):
    return (.5*h**2/m) * (n*np.pi)**2

def k(n):
    return (n*np.pi)**2

ns = np.arange(1, 5)
plt.scatter(k(ns), E(ns))
plt.show()
```